# Is chrome able to read videos?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I have tried multiple formats (mp4, webm, ogg) with firefox and chrome, but none of the browsers seem to load my video.
I don't think it is because of the src, I can follow the link and i brings me to the folder, where my video is. Do you think, Chrome and Firefox can't open these formats?

```
  <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto" *ngIf="enableFirstSectionYes">
            <video width="600" height="240" controls autoplay>
              <source src="src\app\videos\video.webm" type="video/webm">
          </video>
```

Comment: Your `src=""` attribute is invalid: HTTP uses forward-slashes (`/`) to separate path-components, not backslashes (``\``). Use `<source src="src/app/videos/video.webm" type="video/webm">`

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I tried this a well, but it still doesnt load the video

Comment: Check your browser's DevTools' Network activity tab.

Comment: I get a 404 not found

Comment: so sounds like your path is not correct. Where is the html file at and where is the video at?

Comment: Just mentioning that this video is not on the internet, only in my folder

Comment: But I even copied the path of the video, what else is the right path?

Comment: We do not know since we can not see into your computer and see the file structure.

Comment: I use angular, my videos-folder is inside my src/app, where also my video.webm is

Comment: I highly doubt you want `src/app` in your path. You probably want `/videos/video.webm`

Comment: Doesn't work...still 404 not found

Comment: I think it is not possible to load local video files

Answer (score 0):

#### Browser support

According to [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/?search=webm), the `Chrome` and `firefox` should be able to read `.webm` format.
image
[image]
So the reason did not the `browser`'s problem.

#### Angular

In `Angular`, static resource should be place in `assets` folder.

image
[image][image]

Maybe the reason is the video in wrong folder.
Move the video to `assets` folder, and change the `video` tag's `src`

```html
  <video controls autoplay muted>
    <source src="../assets/videos/oceans.mp4" />
  </video>
```

---

I had tested it, and it is works fine.
 my environment is `window11`
[image]